For Rambam, is the explanation of Nach considered Torah shebi’al peh?
Rambam starts off his intro to MT as follows:

כׇּל הַמִּצְוֹת שֶׁנִּתְּנוּ לוֹ לְמֹשֶׁה בְּסִינַי בְּפֵרוּשָׁן נִתְּנוּ. שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר וְאֶתְּנָה לְךָ אֶת לֻחֹת הָאֶבֶן וְהַתּוֹרָה וְהַמִּצְוָה. תּוֹרָה זוֹ תּוֹרָה שֶׁבִּכְתָב. וְהַמִּצְוָה זוֹ פֵּרוּשָׁהּ. וְצִוָּנוּ לַעֲשׂוֹת הַתּוֹרָה עַל פִּי הַמִּצְוָה. וּמִצְוָה זוֹ הִיא הַנִּקְרֵאת תּוֹרָה שֶׁבְּעַל פֶּה.
The mitzvot given to Moses at Mount Sinai were all given together with their explanations,⁠ as implied by [Exodus 24:12]: "And I will give you the tablets of stone, the Torah, and the mitzvah."
"The Torah" refers to the Written Law; "the mitzvah," to its explanation. [God] commanded us to fulfill "the Torah" according to [the instructions of] "the mitzvah." "The mitzvah" is called the Oral Law.

presumably limiting "Torah shebi’al peh" to the traditional instructions regarding how to go about mitzvah performance.
Otoh (HT @RabbiMattSchneeweiss), in Hilchos Talmud Torah 1:12 Rambam seemingly includes the explanation of Nach/Divrei Kabbalah as well in the scope of "Torah shebi’al peh":

וְדִבְרֵי קַבָּלָה בִּכְלַל תּוֹרָה שֶׁבִּכְתָב הֵן וּפֵרוּשָׁן בִּכְלַל תּוֹרָה שֶׁבְּעַל פֶּה.
The "words of the prophetic tradition" are considered part of the Written Law;⁠ and their explanation,⁠ part of the Oral Law.

Does Rambam here intend to enlarge the scope or is he imprecisely generalizing without meaning to include the explanation of Nach/Divrei Kabbalah?

I don't quite understand your question. Are you asking if Rambam holds that (e.g.) Shir Hashirim Rabbah is part of the Torah She'Baal Peh?

@RabbiKaii Perhaps. What do you think is subsumed under "וּפֵרוּשָׁן"?

Are you looking for Rambam's definition of halacha l'Moshe miSinai or Gemiri? That is discussed in the ch.2 of Darka shel Torah, The Path of Torah by Netsiv (also published as introduction to his Emek Sheela). There, Netsiv states that all books of Neviim & Ketuvim became necessary because of the sin of the Golden Calf, as people analytic abilities became corrupted, and they required a lot more material to study to fully understand the depth of Torah. This is how one may approach answering your question.
